# Gaussian functions and currying in Scheme

Tags: scheme, gaussian, currying

I am currently trying to learn Scheme to run FDTD simulations and I am having trouble building a Gaussian function in 2 dimensions.

In a forum I found this possibility for 1D:

```
(define ( (gaussx sigma) x)
   (exp (- (/ (vector3-dot x x) (* 2 sigma sigma)))))
```

which if I understood currying correctly is equivalent to:

```
(define  (gauss sigma)
   (lambda(x)
      (exp (- (/ (vector3-dot x x) (* 2 sigma sigma))))))
```

Now I would like the function to be gaussian along both x and y directions but I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
(define  (gauss sigma)
   (lambda(x)
      (lambda(y)
         (exp (- (/ (+ (vector3-dot y y) (vector3-dot x x)) (* 2 sigma sigma))))
```

When I call

```
(gauss 1)
```

I get the following message:

```
ERROR: Wrong type (expecting real number): # <procedure> #f (y)
```

Does someone see what I am doing wrong? I also tried other solutions but I don't seem to get the logics here...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best regards
Mei

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's need for a double currying here, try this:

```
(define (gauss sigma)
  (lambda (x y)
    (exp (- (/ (+ (vector3-dot y y) (vector3-dot x x)) (* 2 sigma sigma))))))
```

Call it like this:

```
(define gauss-1 (gauss 1))
(gauss-1 some-x some-y)
```

But if you definitely need the double currying, this should work:

```
(define (gauss sigma)
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (y)
      (exp (- (/ (+ (vector3-dot y y) (vector3-dot x x)) (* 2 sigma sigma)))))))
```

Using it like this:

```
(define gauss-1 (gauss 1))
((gauss-1 some-x) some-y)
```